# ReactJS does not loads index.html file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

On going through multiple DOCs I get to know that `index.html` file is the entry point for a React application and all the components we load overrides this file. But if I am making changes to the index.html file that is not reflected in the web page. I am working on integrating Zoom SDKs which needs to include script tags inside the index.html or else JQuery errors are thrown to the console.

Contents of my public/index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://source.zoom.us/1.7.0/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://source.zoom.us/1.7.0/css/react-select.css" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://source.zoom.us/1.7.2/lib/vendor/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://source.zoom.us/1.7.2/lib/vendor/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://source.zoom.us/1.7.2/lib/vendor/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://source.zoom.us/1.7.2/lib/vendor/redux-thunk.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://source.zoom.us/1.7.2/lib/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://source.zoom.us/1.7.2/lib/vendor/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://source.zoom.us/zoom-meeting-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

My index.js configuration:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
  Redirect,
  HashRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch
} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { setStore } from './store/base';

import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import './App.scss';
import MeetingRoom from './containers/MeetingRoom/MeetingRoom';


export const store = configureStore({});
setStore(store);

const routes = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <Switch>  
         <Route component={MeetingRoom} path='/m/:mid/' />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('root'));
```

If I am changing the text inside `<noscript>` tag i.e `You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.` to some other string but it is not getting reflected in the web page. So how my index.html is getting loaded I cannot figure out. Is there any other information I need to provide for getting the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML noscript element defines a section of HTML to be inserted if a script type on the page is unsupported or if scripting is currently turned off in the browser. Add some string inside div element to see on the webpage

Comment: I tried inserting elements and text inside root div element but nothing shows up in the Element section of web page Inspect element!

Comment: That's because the App component is injected there. Before App component renders you can see the text you inserted inside root div. if you want more clarification, look at this https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-snowflake-54zkp?file=/public/index.html

Comment: In my project App.js is not getting rendered, since I had put console.log inside render function of App.js but no console output I am getting. Please check the content of my index.js file there is no injection of App component there. I can't figure out how exactly the page is getting loaded then.

Comment: You have not set any routes for App component. You have a route for MeetingRoom.. Take a look at this https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-chaplygin-4s59j?file=/src/index.js
This should clear your doubts

Comment: I figured out the issue. We are having server in Django, so we are using Django template for the purpose and not React index.html